# Merged audio and merged video duration difference

Tags: ffmpeg

I have some pictures and audio files in a folder and I made list from them so I can concat them using ffmpeg. Here are two example lists and the commands used for concatting:

List of audio files (audios.txt):

```
file audio1.wav
file audio2.wav
file audio3.wav
```

The command: `ffmpeg -f concat -i audios.txt merged.wav`

List of images (images.txt):

```
file image1.png
duration 3.3589115646258505
file image2.png
duration 4.958730158730159
file image3.png
duration 11.687709750566894
```

I'm calculating the image durations based on their respective audio files using Python:

```python
import librosa

def get_duration(path):
    return librosa.get_duration(path=path)
```

The ffmpeg command I use for concatting: `ffmpeg -f concat -i images.txt -c png merged.mp4`

My problem is that in this particular instance I get a 20 seconds long merged.wav which is correct, but my merged.mp4 is only 11 seconds long for some reason. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Seems bugged after a quick look. Try adding the last file again at the end of the inputs with no or very short duration.

Comment: this trick doesn't work with png, but it works with jpg

Comment: you can try to add last png with `duration 0.0` 3 or 4 times, maybe more.

Comment: These seem like really dirty hacks lol